# How to use nhanes data to do mediation analysis

Tags: r

I have been trying to use `nhanes` data to do a mediation analysis. The main model is a logistic regression model.

I tried the mediation package first, but it can't use the weights of the `nhanes` data. I also tried the lavaan.survey package, but it doesn't fit a logistics regression model. Which R package should I use?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you checked the [bruceR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bruceR/index.html) package, specifically the function `PROCESS` in it?

Comment: @medium-dimensional
 Thx for your advice! I didn't try this package, can it analysis models from survey package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mma package. Can analysis the data from nhanes.
I also trying to use nhanes data to do a mediation analysis, It's so difficult.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).